# Replace Adjacent Elements of Circular Array to Make All Elements Equal - DSA INTERVIEW QUESTION

Tags: arrays, dynamic-programming, greedy

You are given a circular array A containing N integers. You can perform the following operation on this array any number of items:

• For each i, replace A[i] by A[i-1], A[i] or A[i+1] i.e. you can keep the current element or replace it by an adjacent element . Note that due to circularity of the array adjacent elements exist even for the first and the last element. In particular, A[i-1] for i=0 is the last element.

Determine the minimum number of steps needed to make all the elements of the array equal.

Input Format The first line contains an integer, N, denoting the number of elements in A. Each line i of the N subsequent lines (where 0 $i< N) contains an integer describing A[i]. Constraints 1 <= N <= 10^3

Sample input: 4 2 2 1 1 => Sample output: 1

Sample input:3 1 1 1 => Sample output: 0

Sample input:4 1 2 3 4 => Sample output: 2

I tried to Create a Hashmap to store freq of each element.
Then iterate over the hashmap - take out the element with highest freq, after that substract it with the length of array - to get the no. of elements to be changed.
But the question says - we can replace adjacent ele, and array is circular in nature.
Please help me to code this.
TIA.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I thought of with is we will choose the element to replace every other element. Now, let's say the number is x.
Now, for all blocks of x. We will mark an index just before the block and just after the block. And, now we can just find the y = max (j - i + 1) where i, and j are marked indices, without any x between them.
Answer will be ciel(y/2).

For example, in the let's say A = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 1, 7]
Here, for 1 it will be:
So, A = [`1, 1, 1`, **2**, **3**, `1, 1,` **4**, 5, 6, **8**, `1,` **7**]
Here, I have marked the indexes as mentioned above in bold.
Our answer will be 2 here, as in case of i = 7, j = 10. We get the answer for 1 as 2. Similarly. We will consider all other unique elements in the array.

Code in C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    vector<int> arr(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    int res = 0;
    int max_dist = 0;

    for (int num = 1; num <= n; num++) {
        vector<int> indexes;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == num) {
                indexes.push_back(i);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < indexes.size(); i++) {
            max_dist = max(max_dist, indexes[i] - indexes[i-1] - 1);
        }

        if (!indexes.empty()) {
            max_dist = max(max_dist, n + indexes[0] - indexes.back() - 1);
        }
    }

    res = (max_dist + 1) / 2;
    cout << res << endl;

    return 0;
}
```